# type error: 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python

```
# Quidditch

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, base_energy):
        """
        Players have a name, and begin with base_energy.
        """
        self.name = name
        self.base_energy = base_energy

    def energy(self):
        return self.base_energy

class Beater(Player):
    role = "bludgers"

    def energy(self, time):
        """
        Returns the amount of energy left after playing for time minutes. 
        After playing for time minutes, Beaters lose their base energy level 
        divided by the number of minutes. If time is 0, catch the ZeroDivisionError 
        and print "You can't divide by zero!" instead.
        >>> fred = Beater("Fred Weasley", 640)
        >>> fred.energy(40)
        624.0
        >>> fred.energy(0)
        You can't divide by zero!
        """
        self.time = time
        try:
            self.energy = self.base_energy - (self.base_energy/(self.time))
            return self.energy
        except Exception as error:
            print("You can't divide by zero!")
```

Hi I am doing my homework and I suppose to use exception to avoid the zero division error, however, I encountered another error which says the 'float' object is not callable. I believe the error occured because of `self.energy = self.base_energy - (self.base_energy/(self.time))` this line of code. But i don't know how to fix it. Help please!

Comment: You assign to `energy`, which is at that moment a method, the next time you cal it, you indeed no longer call the method, but the float that was the result.

Comment: Just don't assign a value to `self.energy`.